# How to create listbox in kivy python?

Tags: python, kivy

I'm writing a file manager in kivy. How can I add listbox into kivy app?
And How can I bind functions to double-click.

Comment: You can probably do something like Buttons in a GrdiLayout in a ScrollView. As for the double-click, you can check for double tap in an `on_touch_down` method using [is_double_tap](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.input.motionevent.html?highlight=motionevent#kivy.input.motionevent.MotionEvent.is_double_tap) property of the `touch` event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO, you could make your 'listbox'  using a `RecycleView` with `Label`s or `BoxLayout`s.

Something like:

```
RecycleView:
    id: rv
    viewclass: 'Label'
    RecycleBoxLayout:
        default_size: None, dp(56)
        default_size_hint: 1, None
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
        orientation: 'vertical'
```

Then somewhere in your `.py` file:

```
...
dat = []
for l in ["label1", "label2"," label3"]:
    dat.insert(0,{'text':l,color=(1,1,0,1)}

self.ids.rv.data = dat
```

Note that, the `viewclass` defines what will be the contents of your `RecycleView` , as such, this should be a valid Kivy class which in this case is just a list of `Label`s. For something more complicated, you can create your own widgets